# Image with opacity change and circle overlay?

Tags: css

I feel like it's not that hard but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm mainly having problems with having the circle overlay appear when hovering over the image. This is what I've come up with

```
.box {
color: #212121;
padding: 0;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
width: 225px;
height: 85px;
background: #ffffff;
}

.box img{
text-align: center;
width: 75px;
height: 75px;
-moz-transition-duration:0.6s;
-webkit-transition-duration:0.6s;
-o-transition-duration:0.6s;
}

.box img:hover .circle{
opacity:0.5;
-moz-transition-duration:0.6s;
-webkit-transition-duration:0.6s;
-o-transition-duration:0.6s;
 }

.circle{
position: absolute;    
text-align:center;
width:30px;
height:30px;
background-color:#fff;
font-family: calibri;
font-size:18px;
line-height:28px;
padding:15px;
margin: -70px 8px;
opacity:0;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
-moz-transition-duration:0.6s;
-webkit-transition-duration:0.6s;
-o-transition-duration:0.6s;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML in question? And maybe even make a fiddle to show your code in action.

Comment: the `-moz-` prefixes are no longer needed, cleared those from your code. Not sure about the `-o-` and `-webkit-`.

Comment: @Martijn According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions), if it wasn't for Android, you could ditch `-webkit-`, and `-o-` apparently was never a huge thing to begin with (only for one version). Anyway, I think editing the code of a question, because something is no longer needed is a terrible idea! You might be accidentally hiding what's actually causing the problem. Sure, that's not the case here, but you're still effectively altering the question. And not to mention: Including prefixed versions doesn't hurt and you might add support for an additional .1% of all users.

Comment: Rolled it back. Doubt this is the issue, but your point remains

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you expect the `img` to have `.circle` as a child which is not possible as `img` is a self contained element.

As far as your HTML is correct:

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="self.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Your CSS should be more like below. You should move `:hover` declaration onto `.box` so it will become available for circle (which is now a direct child). Other styling issues are not really related and are matter of what you want to achieve there

```
.box {
    color: #212121;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 85px;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.box img {
    text-align: center;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    -moz-transition-duration:0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.6s;
    -o-transition-duration:0.6s;
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;    
    text-align:center;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#fff;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:28px;
    padding:15px;
    margin: -70px 8px;
    opacity:0;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-transition-duration:0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.6s;
    -o-transition-duration:0.6s;
}

.box:hover .circle {
    opacity:0.5;
    -moz-transition-duration:0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.6s;
    -o-transition-duration:0.6s;
}
```